# Casting a string to a boolean operator (<, <=, >, >=)

Tags: excel, casting, excel-formula, boolean-expression

In cell `A1`, there can be either `<`, `<=`, `>` or `>=` (of string).

In cell `B1`, there's the threshold's value of int.

From `A3`, there are values of int.

```
+---+-----+----+
|   | A   | B  |
+---+-----+----+
| 1 | <   | 15 |
| 2 |     |    |
| 3 | 10  |    |
| 4 | 20  |    |
| 5 | ... |    |
+---+-----+----+
```

The value in `A3` should be copied in `B3` if and only if it respects the boolean operator (`A1`) and the threshold (`B1`). Otherwise, `B3` should be `#N/A`. Of course, the same for `A4`/`B4`, `A5`/`B5`, etc.

In that example, `B3` should be `10` and `B4` should be `#N/A`, because 10 is less than 15, but 20 isn't.

Here is a formula I created which works great, but which is a bit long (this is for `B3`):

```
=IF($A$1 = "<"; IF($A3 < $B$1; $A3; NA()); IF($A$1 = "<="; IF($A3 <= $B$1; $A3; NA()); IF($A$1 = ">"; IF($A3 > $B$1; $A3; NA()); IF($A3 >= $B$1; $A3; NA()))))
```

The same in a more digest way:

```
=IF(
    $A$1 = "<";
    IF($A3 < $B$1;$A3; NA());
    IF(
        $A$1 = "<=";
        IF($A3 <= $B$1; $A3; NA());
        IF(
            $A$1 = ">";
            IF($A3 > $B$1; $A3; NA());
            IF($A3 >= $B$1; $A3; NA())
        )
    )
)
```

Is there any more convenient way to do that job? Casting from a string to an operator would be great, but yeah, I dunno any programing language capable of doing such kind of stuff `:)` Ideally, it should be something like `=IF($A3 $A$1 $B$1; $A3; NA())`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this formula

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A3,$A$1&$B$1),A3,NA())
```

Comment: +1: Good one.  If it was acceptable to have 0 instead of #n/a one could also use `=SUMIF(A3;A1&B1)`

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is based completely on [this article](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2212496,00.asp), but it seems like it would fit here. There are two ways you can do it: using a named range and a UDF. Both ways basically take advantage of Excel's 'hidden' EVALUATE function.

**Named Range**

To use a named range, you define a name (in this case, I used `Compare`) and assign it the following value (note this is all relative the ranges in my sheet, so you may need to adjust):

```
=EVALUATE("IF(" & A3 & $A$1 & $B$1 &"," & A3 & ",NA())")
```

Note that the ranges appear to automatically update with the sheet name prefixed.

[image]

**UDF**

Add the following as a UDF:

```
Function Evalu(ByVal S As String) As String
  Evalu = Evaluate(S)
End Function
```

And then enter the following formula:

```
=INT(IFERROR(Evalu("IF(" & A3 & $A$1 & $B$1 &"," & A3 & ",NA())"),NA()))
```

The double `NA()`'s are a bit hacky, but the Evalu function returns a #VALUE error instead of #N/A, so this clumsily forces the error you want. Also, the function returns a string, so you need to cast the result as an integer. I somewhat prefer the first method :)

[image]